# How can I use a UITextfield to call "when clicked" a UITableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

Textfield to call when clicked a UITableview, then return to the calling Textfield the value of the string value of cell selected in UITableview?

Sorry but I have searched and googled this and still can't seem to find any guidance.  Also this is for an iPhone app only, so I can't utilise popovers

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you select any row from table insert one more row(cell) in table(next to the selected cell) which having UITextField as part of context!

This method get call on selection of cell 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}

you can remove the cell once your text entries get finished!, for that add event on UITextField.

events name-UIControlEventEditingDidEnd || UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit